# Specify different email address for Test Flight?

Tags: ios, ipad, testflight

I want to specify a different email address for Test Flight. The iOS app appears to assume a particular Apple ID:

[image]

I went to *Settings → iTunes & App Store → Apple ID* and changed the ID to the test flight email I want to use. But that's not working (its asking me to sign in, which won't work since this is a throw away test flight email address).

The device I use is used by other folks, so I really don't want my Apple ID on it.

How do I specify an alternate email address for testing?

Comment: To clarify, Apple released their own TestFlight app, at the time they killed the original TestFlight app. The Apple app has the same limitation: the way to change the apple ID used by TestFlight, is to change the device's "iTunes & App Store" id. The good news is there is an alternative now: External Testers / Public Link. This link can then be used on different devices - and can be disabled. See App Store Connect for details.

Answer (score 7):

Test Flight is now linked via your Apple ID that's signed into the device at the top.

This was running on iPad with OS 14.3. It's the same as on iPhone as well with that newer version as well.

Go to Settings -> Top Link (name, icon, Apple ID, iCloud...).  That email account must be setup in the Test Flight section of the Apple Developers account on their website as well.

https://developer.apple.com

If setup properly, you will then see the same icon for your account in the Test Flight app and should see the available apps. If no apps, well, that's another stackoverflow article away..  ;-)

Comment: What if I want to use a different account to test apps, or if I have multiple Apple IDs for different client projects. How stupid it was for Apple to remove the ability to sign in inside the TestFlight app itself...

Answer (score 6):

Just add the new email as a tester... open the email on whichever device you want to use.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I don't see where I can do that. Is there a secret knock in this app to do it? (I added the image with the only setting I could find).

Comment: Are you using the web site?

Comment: No. I have the Test Flight app installed. (Or are you telling me I have to use the website?)

Comment: Give the site a spin, you can add testers there

Comment: *"Just add the new email as a tester."* - to clarify, this is not done in testflight. In browser, someone with admin or developer rights for the app, logs in to App-Store-Connect / App-Name-Here / TestFlight. Adds email as external tester. Then tapping on email link on that device should open TestFlight, with that app shown. If not, there should be a "Redeem Code" you can type into TestFlight.

Comment: I had a similar issue and needed to make sure my apple id under "Settings > Your name > Media & Purchases" was the same as my main apple id.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for separation global Apple ID from the one I want to use in a Test Flight.
Next approach helped me on iOS 16.6 device:

1. Sign in with a general Apple ID.
2. Navigate to "Settings -> Apple ID -> Media & Purchases".
3. Proceed with "Sign Out".
4. Press on "Media & Purchases" again.
5. Log in by choosing the option "Not a *current AppleID*"

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue., the account which was reflecting in my TestFlight was the same as the account I used in my Appstore App. When I changed the account connected to Appstore, to the account I wanted to change, the same was reflected in TestFlight and I could access the Apps released in TestFlight.